# Last iteration of a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I want to do something like this:

```
for (var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
   document.write(i + ",");
}
```

It shows a result like:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
```

But I want to remove the last ",", and the result should be like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Comment: why dont you use javascript join() method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check wether you have hit the end of the loop ( i == 10):

```
for (var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    document.write(i + (i==10 ? '': ','));
}
```

Here's a fiddle:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9YUNb/)

Answer (score 19):

You should use `.join` instead:

```
var txt = [];                          //create an empty array
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    txt.push(i);                       //push values into array
}

console.log(txt.join(","));            //join all the value with ","
```

Answer (score 5):

You might simply test when generating :

```
for (var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
   document.write(i);
   if (i<9)  document.write(',');
}
```

Note that when you start from an array, which might be your real question behind the one you ask, there is the convenient `join` function :

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
document.write(arr.join(',')); // writes "1,2,3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This-

```
str="";
for (var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
   str=str+i + ",";
}
str.substr(0,str.length-1);
document.write(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
 var arr = new Array();
 for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
 }
 var output = arr.join(',');
 document.write(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    if (i == 10) {
        document.write(i);
    }
    else {
        document.write(i + ",");
    }
}
```